# OpenCV Image processing

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have an Image that I would like to zoom into and view at high detail. It is of unknown size and mostly black and white with some text on it. When I zoom in the text becomes unreadable and I thought it was to do with not having enough pixels/texels to display so I upscaled the image by a factor of 2. Now that I have scaled it, it is still unreadable.

Then I started to use OpenCV with :

```
void resizeFirst(){
  Mat src = imread( "../floor.png", 1 );
  Mat tmp;
  resize(src,tmp,Size(),3,3,INTER_CUBIC);
  Mat dst = tmp.clone();
  Size s(3,3);
  //blur( tmp, dst, s, Point(-1,-1) );//homogeneous
  GaussianBlur(tmp, dst, s, 3);//gaussian
  //medianBlur ( tmp, dst, 5 );//median
  //bilateralFilter ( tmp, dst, 5, 5*2, 5/2 );
  addWeighted(tmp, 1.5, dst, -0.5, 0, dst);
  imwrite("sharpenedImage.png",dst);
}

void blurFirst(){
  Mat src = imread( "../floor.png", 1 );
  Size s(3,3);
  Mat dst;
  GaussianBlur(src, dst, s, 3);//gaussian
  addWeighted(src, 2, dst, -1, 0, dst);
  Mat tmp;
  resize(dst,tmp,Size(),3,3,INTER_CUBIC);
  imwrite("sharpenedImage0.png",tmp);
}
```

and the output is better but the image still isnt sharp. Does anyone have any ideas on how to keep text sharp when zooming into an image?

EDIT: below are sample images.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Enhanced Image]

The first one is the smaller res original and the second I resized and tried to do gaussian sharpening as per below

Comment: Too much CSI? ;-) You can not get details where the are none in the source image. But try INTER_LANCZOS4.

Comment: thats what i thought, but another Android app is using the same image and when you zoom into it, you can very easily read the text. you can also tell that there was some kind of processing done on it. The contours of the walls on the image also look very sharp.

Comment: Can you post example images (input and output)?

Comment: @Dobi PFA. maybe if I run the blur/weight again. I wonder if its a recursive process?

Comment: making it do it 5 times over seems to increase the smoothness! but at the cost of color since each time the white pixels are bleeding into the black.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you could post images of the other app that magically improves the image detail while zooming.

Answer (score 2):

Resize function offers different interpolation methods

```
INTER_NEAREST nearest-neighbor interpolation
INTER_LINEAR bilinear interpolation (used by default)
INTER_AREA resampling using pixel area relation. It may be the preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method
INTER_CUBIC bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
INTER_LANCZOS4 Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood
```

try all the interpolation methods and use the one that suits you the most. The resize function will however change the aspect ratio of your image.

Comment: resize can change the aspect ratio, but here i'm using the same multiplier for each side. "To shrink an image, it will generally look best with CV_INTER_AREA interpolation, whereas to enlarge an image, it will generally look best with CV_INTER_CUBIC (slow) or CV_INTER_LINEAR (faster but still looks OK)."